# GCM RegId Validation Token Lengths Mismatch

Tags: android, cloud, google-cloud-messaging

Validations is that c2dm uses tokens 162 long and GCM uses tokens 183. However, when I follow the google tutorial on GCM, I'm getting registration IDs that are 162 character in length.

[Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

How do I ensure that am getting the right registration ID when I'm sending it to the server? I'm using:

```
if (gcm == null) {
    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(_context);
}
regId = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
```

and getting the regId. regId is of length 162.

Comment: As C2DM is GCM (C2DM is the old name/API), where does it say that GCM tokens are 183 characters long?

Answer (score 1):

The GCM Registration ID doesn't have a constant length. It's length is limited by 4096 bytes, but in practice it's much smaller. I've never seen registraiton IDs of more than 256 bytes (The largest I've even seen was a little over 200, I don't remember the exact length).

You have no way of validating the registration ID your serrver gets from the app (other than sending a message to GCM server for that registration ID and getting a successful response).

Answer (score 0):

GCM registraction ID can not confirm it doesn't limit the length in my case sometimes 118bytes or large.
you can confirm the reg ID by your serve.